# Why do filters in Visual Studio 2019 appear to override file extensions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I created a very simple project to test a separate question I have.

Pointer.cpp

```
struct PtrHolder {
    int num;
    int* ptr;

    PtrHolder(int i) {
        num = i;
        ptr = new int[i];
        ptr[0] = i;
    }

    ~PtrHolder() {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    PtrHolder holder(2);
    PtrHolder* holderAddr = new PtrHolder(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I added a file to my project and created this class, but as a header file accidentally. I simply changed its extension and dragged it to the `Source Files` filter view.[image: Solution Explorer].

Debugging would fail and build output would show no `.cpp`s, despite physically having one.

I copied the source code, deleted the file, and properly added a `.cpp` file to the project. Builds just fine now. Thus, leading to my question.

Comment: Well you've destroyed the evidence now, but was it marked as 'Exclude from build'?

Comment: Yeah, the project file from when it was broken would have been useful to debug this. My guess is it was still marked as "C/C++ Header" in the type field.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, I created another header and did the same thing to it. In the file properties, it is a "C/C++ Header". There is no option that looks like "Source" or anything, though. Should it be "C/C++ Compiler" to act as a source file?

Comment: @PaulSanders This new file is blank for it's Exclude from Build option.

Comment: @RayshaunThompson Yes, it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that filters take precedent over file types, but extensions themselves are not utilized by Visual Studios. The file's "item type" property determines how it is treated by IDE's compiler. Header files are "C/C++ Header" items and source files are "C/C++ Compiler" items.

Answer (score -1):

Using this method to convert .h into .cpp files cannot generate .exe files, which means that Visual Studio currently cannot directly convert .h and .cpp files to each other.
I suggest you refer to this [issue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26264/why-isnt-it-possible-to-switch-between-header-and-cpp-in-visual-studio).